# How to not hide base class members while inheriting in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am not getting the base class member in this code. Please suggest. I'm a rookie here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CaseStudy1
{  
    class base1
    {
        protected string name = "";
        public base1() {}
        public base1(string dad)
        {
            this.name = dad;
        }
    }

    class child1 : base1
    {
        private string name = "";

        public child1()
        {
            this.name = base.name;
        }

        public void show()
        {
            base1 b1 = new base1("Daddy");
            Console.WriteLine("base name"+base.name);
            Console.WriteLine("child's name" + name);            
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            child1 c1 = new child1();
            c1.show();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Need more explanation about your issue.

Comment: You should try studying inheritance a little bit more. The way you want to use it is odd. in your first main line you create a child object but you are not calling its base constructor ... in your function show you are creating a new base instance but you are referring to your child instance. If you use inheritance your created object is both, base1 and child1. So don't view them as separated things.

Answer (score 2):

In C# Inheritance, what you have as a "child" class is not really a child (being owned by the base) but a more specific version of the base (as like a football being a specific kind of ball).  The base class and the inherited class are the same actual object.  Therefore, the `new` keyword is out of place, since what you want is the base class's name, not a new base object all together.  By using the same name for a property in both the base and the inherited class, you are "hiding" the property in the base, since a single object can't have the same property twice (in your example, your object can't have 2 different `name`.  If what you want to do is have the inherited class know the name of the base, they need to be different properties.

The best way to think of it is that if you use `new` to create an object, that object will have every property and method of itself and any class **above** it in the class tree, so a `child1` object would have the `child1` and the `base1` properties and methods, but a new `base1` object only has the `base1` properties and methods.

As a side effect, a `child1` object can be used in any statement that requires a `base1` object, since a `child1` object **is** a `base1` object.

Answer (score 0):

Here within the Show method you create the new instance of base1 class.So you cannot read from setted value from using `base.name`.because of b1 is new instance.

You can use as follows.

```
    class base1
    {
        protected string name { get; set; }
        public base1() { }
    }
    class child1 : base1
    {
        private string name = "";
        public void show()
        {
            base.name = "Daddy";
            this.name = base.name;
            Console.WriteLine("base name" + base.name);
            Console.WriteLine("child's name" + name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But as @AndrewCounts pointed out, this would still be hiding the `name` property in the base class. The `child1` class should not have a property that is identical to a property in its base class